# Add/change button overlay of video record when using AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, ios, overlay, avfoundation, video-recording

I am currently implementing video functionality into an iPhone app that requires the user to be able to 'Select and Play' a video and 'Record and Play' a video using the AVFoundation API. Similar to that shown in the tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios).

No problems so far implementing the functionality, however I now need to change the buttons shown recording a video for example - thus creating a custom overlay. For example the record button needs to be altered.

Comment: You might want to include some code sample or walkthrough of what you have tried. Have you made some progress?

Comment: I don't know where to start that's the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have done this before is to disable the controls from MPMovePlayerController, then put a UIImageView with your controls over the top, then put a UIView with UITapGestureRecognizer on top of that to detect when your controls are pressed.

Disabling the controls:

```
[_videoPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
```

Gesture recognizer:

```
touchLayer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapVideoControlOverlay:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

[touchLayer addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```